# SOQL not returning results in Test Apex class

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I am having a simple test class as below

```
 @isTest
public class codecovertess {

    @isTest
     public static void test1()
    {
        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name='testppcodecove';
        Account x = [select id,name from Account LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('x value==='+x.Name);
        ApexPages.StandardController stdController  = new ApexPages.StandardController(x);
        tess t = new tess(stdController);
        t.getGreeting();
        String vartest=t.testvar;
        System.assertEquals('a', 'a');
    }
}
```

When i am using this test class i am getting an error as

> FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to
>   SObject

But when i am removing `@isTest` and running like a normal Apex class it is working fine,i am confused ,shouldnt we use SOQL in Test class.Can anyone please help me understand why i am not able to run it in Test class.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you need to first insert the account record. Check my comments.

```
Account a = new Account();
a.Name='testppcodecove';
insert a/insert here
Account x = [select id,name from Account LIMIT 1];
System.debug('x value==='+x.Name);
ApexPages.StandardController stdController  = new ApexPages.StandardController(x);
tess t = new tess(stdController);
t.getGreeting();
String vartest=t.testvar;
System.assertEquals('a', 'a'); //Also this assert is not useful you can check better condition here
```

Also you should check [Apex Testing Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing) to get better understanding.

Comment: But tushar ,we have a record in Account object when i run the query i am getting a record so y should i insert i can use the existing record right?

Comment: @srikanth In test classes we don't get system data unless we use `SeeAlldata = true`. Which is not recommended. Its a best practices to create our own test data. Thats why I suggest you to go on trailhead modules.

Comment: @srikanth then you can accept this answer and close the question.